# No Sound output from my built-in speakers (Dell N5040)

Tags: 10.04, sound

I am using ubuntu **10.04 LTS** desktop and I don't have any sound output from the built-in speakers in my Dell N5040

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit this file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and then add a line in its end.

Use the following commands in a terminal

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf &`

Now add the following line at its end:

`options snd-hda-intel model=generic`

Now reboot your computer. It should solve your problem. If the solution doesn’t work it is likely that the term model = generic may not work in all the cases as sometimes it depends on the model of your sound card.

Find your sound card by typing `aplay -l | grep card` in a terminal

You can try replacing the word generic by the following words depending upon your model of Dell laptop:

`options snd-hda-intel model=ref`

[Refrence](http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/06/how-to-solve-no-sound-through-laptop-integrated-speakers-in-ubuntu-11-04/)